# Stored Procedure only fully works in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a very simple check procedure that takes in a comma delimited string and verifies that records with that key have the correct status. At the end of the procedure an audit is created with the comma delimited string,a count of items in the string and a count of updates made. The audit always reflects 0 updates. However when I run the procedure in SSMS with the same login as the job that runs the procedure I get updates. I know there is something simple occurring but cannot see it. The routine is specified below

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @loads Table(shipmentnumber varchar(20))
declare @passinfo Table (ID int, fieldname varchar(50), field nvarchar(max)) 


select @info = replace(@info, '"','')

declare @cnt1 int, @cnt2 int, @error varchar(100)
insert into @loads 
select rtrim(ltrim(splitdata)) from dbo.fnsplitstring(@info, ',')

set @cnt1 = @@rowcount


update loads 
set loadstatus = 102 
where shipmentnumber in (select shipmentnumber from @loads)
and loadstatus <> 102

set @cnt2 = @@rowcount

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ShipperSPAudit]
       ([SP]
       ,[parm1]
       ,[parm2],parm3,parm4
       ,[requesteddate]
       , userid)
 VALUES
       ('CPCheckCancel'
       ,cast(@shipper as varchar)
       ,@info, cast(@cnt1 as varchar), cast(@cnt2 as varchar)
       ,getdate()
       ,@userid)

END
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: Many doubts. You only posted part of a longer script / procedure. You declare passinfo but never use it. You use shipper (casting poorly) but don't declare it. The problem is likely to be elsewhere. Start by comparing the content of info before and after you sanitize it. It may be that whatever calls this procedure does not provide the information in the manner expected - which, of course, you do when you run it directly.

Comment: The only lines missing are

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a rational explanation to why it would work in SSMS and not as a scheduled job. Changed the line of code that reads select rtrim(ltrim(splitdata)) from dbo.fnsplitstring(@info, ',') to select substring(splitdata,1,8) from dbo.fnsplitstring(@info, ',') as I know the incoming comma delimited fields should be 8 characters in length. The code now works when running as a job and when running in SSMS

Comment: Theory - The data coming in from the external system was padding with something other than spaces so the rtrim and ltrim had no effect. The data was then stored in a audit table in a  varchar(max) field. The special characters thus were lost and when the data was retrived to be used in SSMS the rtrim and ltrim worked